# Bash/Zsh issues with stty raw -echo

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, stty

This issue has ariseb because I use reverse shells quite a lot and often need to upgrade the shell to enable tab autocomplete or cursor use.  The issue is not just on reverse shells though, even if I use the following input in my own terminal I get the same result.  I use Terminator, but have also tried this in Terminal and get the same issue.

The first method I tried was:

```
<Ctrl-z>
stty raw -echo
fg
<enter>
<enter>
```

This would result in me being unable to enter text though (bad characters appear e.g. ^M for enter):

[Shell working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deEKi.png)

Suspend with Ctrl-z, "stty raw -echo", hit enter twice, then fg to resume (ignore the "whoami"...!):

[Ctrl-z, stty raw -echo,  (please ignore the "whoami"...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrBbg.png)

At the bottom you can see, when **fg** is entered I can enter text but if I press ENTER I get ^M.

Having looked through other posts I have tried two things.  One is to ensure icrnl is set to ON, it is.  The other was to try "stty raw -echo; fg" as one command instead of two.  This produced a different result.  It works better, but the prompt then moves across the screen whenever I press enter:

[stty raw -echo; fg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qDJx.png)

I have tried to do this in bash instead of zsh, I get the same result.  Does anyone know how I may be able to solve this?  I'll attach my stty below for info:

```
└─$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 46; columns 116; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Bizarelly, having had this issue for weeks, I've literally just fixed it...!

Prior to suspending and doing stty... Changing the python command has fixed it:

Original: `python -c "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')"`

New (works): `python -c 'import pty;pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'`

Removing the space between pty; pty has fixed it. Then do the commands as above but include ;fg after stty raw -echo. Tab autocomplete etc all works! –

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you want to include additional details, amend your question please. BTW, I think this question should go to [su], not stackoverflow.